# How to use Asynchronous task inside for loop in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, for-loop, asynchronous, nsurlsession

I am using google map In my project. I am calculating place distance for current location nd showing this is TableView. now there are multiple places and I want to show it in tableView. for each place and its distance from current location i need to call google distanceMatrix Api. I am able to store Places cordinate inside array and looping through that array I am calling distance martix api.

here is code

```
 func calculateDistance(type : String)
    {
        let currentLocationCordinate = "\(userCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(userCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

        var url = String()
        var remoteUrl = NSURL()
        var request = NSURLRequest()
        var session = NSURLSession()
        var locatioArrayIndex = 0

        //locationArray Stores Cordinate of nearby array
        for locatioArrayIndex in 0...locationArray.count-1

        {
            placeCordinationArray = "\(locationArray[locatioArrayIndex].coordinate.latitude),\(locationArray[locatioArrayIndex].coordinate.longitude)"

            url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=\(currentLocationCordinate)&destinations=\(placeCordinationArray)&key=\(key)"


            remoteUrl = NSURL(string: url)!

            request = NSURLRequest(URL: remoteUrl)
            let config1 = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            session = NSURLSession(configuration: config1)

            // Asych start here
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in


            // Convert server json response to NSDictionary
            do {

                let convertedJsonIntoDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])

                let rows = convertedJsonIntoDict["rows"] as! NSArray

                let elements = rows[0]

                let element1 = elements["elements"] as! NSArray

                let distance = element1[0]

                let distanceDictionary = distance["distance"]

                let testDistance = distanceDictionary!!["text"]  as! String!
                self.distanceMeter = testDistance
                self.placeDistantArray.append(self.distanceMeter)

                    if (locatioArrayIndex == 9)
                    {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        {
                            self.segueCheck = true
                            self.searchActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            self.searchActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                   })
                }
                    //
                    print("LOCATION ARRAY INDEXINSIDE",locatioArrayIndex)

                }

                catch let error as NSError
                {
                    print("SOME ERROR ",error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })

            task.resume()


        }// For Loop CLosed

      }
```

I am storing distance in **self.placeDistantArray** Array. and after that reloading tableview with its data. but values in **self.placeDistantArray** are reapeting sometimes. and tableview get sometime array index error

Comment: I think you need to Re-initialise array again before the for loop like: ` self.placeDistantArray.removeAllObjects()
self.placeDistantArray = NSMutableArray()`

Answer (score 2):

You code was very very unclean and not readable at all, so I cleaned it:

```
func calculateDistanceUpdatingUI(type : String)
{
    //locationArray Stores Cordinate of nearby array
    for (index, location) in locationArray.enumerate()
    {
        if let remoteUrl = distanceCalculationURLFrom(userCurrentLocation, toDestination: location) {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: remoteUrl)
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

            // clear array
            self.placeDistantArray.removeAll()

            // request distance
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

                do
                {
                    if let distanceMeter = try self.testDistanceFrom(data) {
                        self.distanceMeter = distanceMeter
                        self.placeDistantArray.append(distanceMeter)
                    }

                    if (index == 9)
                    {
                        self.updateUI()
                    }

                    print("LOCATION ARRAY INDEXINSIDE", index)
                }
                catch let error as NSError
                {
                    print("SOME ERROR ", error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })

            task.resume()
        }
    }
}

private func updateUI()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        self.segueCheck = true
        self.searchActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.searchActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

private func distanceCalculationURLFrom(origin: CLLocation, toDestination destination: CLLocation) -> NSURL?
{
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins="
    urlString += "\(origin.coordinate.latitude),\(origin.coordinate.longitude)&destinations="
    urlString += "\(destination.coordinate.latitude),\(destination.coordinate.longitude)&key=\(key)"
    return NSURL(string: urlString)
}

private func testDistanceFrom(data: NSData?) throws -> String?
{
    guard let data = data else {
        return nil
    }
    let convertedJsonIntoDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
    if let rows = convertedJsonIntoDict["rows"] as? NSArray where rows.count > 0,
        let element1 = rows[0]["elements"] as? NSArray where element1.count > 0,
        let distanceDictionary = element1[0]["distance"] as? NSDictionary,
        let testDistance = distanceDictionary["text"] as? String
    {
        return testDistance
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here goes some advice:

- **You should not use forced unwrapping so lightly.**
- You should try to avoid using old style for loops, try to use fast enumeration (more readable).
- **Your functions should not have side effects.** If you call your function `calculateDistance` it should do just that, calculate the distance. Not change variables such as `placeCordinationArray` or update the UI.
- You should try to split up your code and make smaller functions. If you have to add comments like `// For Loop CLosed` it's definitely too large
- You should not initialise Object you won't be using (as in `var request = NSURLRequest()`)
- Try to use correct words, such as `coordinate` instead of `cordination` or `location` instead of `locatio`.

as @Jigar Tarsariya said, I also cleaned the array before it is filled again.

Comment: Thanks for clean code, and Tips. I tried this code , it giving result as the values stored in placeDistantArray array are correct but in every run it stores on different index and loding table with correct value of wrong index

Comment: @KomalK I don't understand what you mean, can you explain.

Comment: I am calling given function like this : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ calculateDistanceUpdatingUI("SomeType")}).  when program excutes values in self.placeDistantArray are ["d1","d2","d4","d6","d3","d5"] and if re executes  values in self.placeDistantArray are ["d1","d3","d4","d2","d3","d5"] . This is dummy data. So thing is thought data in Array is same it get stores on random index

Comment: you don't need to do `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`, just call `calculateDistanceUpdatingUI("SomeType") `. The index is random, because index 1 may complete before index 3, since it is async.

Comment: What you should do is to call google's api only once (you probably get blocked very fast if you don't). And get the ordered list from the elements that are returned from the request.

Comment: instead of `destinations=dest.lat,dest.long&key` do `destinations=dest1.lat,dest1.long|dest2.lat,dest2.long|...&key`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406354/reload-uitableview-from-different-data-from-different-api  please have a look of this code.

Comment: I calling dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), just call calculateDistanceUpdatingUI("SomeType") in this way because I am taking destination cordinate from Nearby search API and then storing it in Array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112918/discussion-between-komal-k-and-simplebob).